# is python -m SimpleHTTPServer a security risk, and if it is how do I turn it off

Tags: webserver

So my noob self turned on `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, not thinking about how to turn it off, is there any way to kill it?

Comment: If by "turned on" you mean that you started the process, you can kill it. Or reboot your computer. ;) Anyways, what do you mean by "security risk"? This depends on what you are using it for, in what context and what you're trying to protect.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible to assess risk without taking into account other factors such as what user you ran it as, any firewall(s) you may be using, and your network configuration (such as routers and port forwarding).

In any case, you can kill it the same way you would kill any other process e.g.

```
pkill -f SimpleHTTPServer
```

(you should see something like

```
[1]+  Terminated              python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

by way of confirmation).

Answer (score 2):

If you are sitting behind a NAT (you are using a simple router in home), if there are any firewall on your router or PC you are safe.

To stop this command after running it you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> like all other commands.

If you ran it in the background so as others suggest it you should find the process and kill it:

```
$ pgrep -a python
14332 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then:

```
$ kill -2 14332
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the HTTP server process is running by opening up terminal then typing

`ps aux | grep HTTP`

and see if it is there.

If the process is running, type

`kill -9 PID`

with PID being the process identifier of the HTTP server.

Alternatively, you could reboot your OS and then the process should not be running.